# How to solve the following left recursion?

Tags: formal-grammars, compilers, parsers

A common left recursion:

```
A -> Aa | B
```

can be solve by transforming it into:

```
A  -> BA'
A' -> aA' | E
```

However, I face another similar yet different left recursion when I'm writing my compiler:

```
A -> (A|B) a
```

So, my question is, how to solve such left recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting `(A|B) a` as `Aa | Ba` allows you to apply the solution you already have (with `Ba` instead of `B`).